# Integral of function with two linearily scaled variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have a known function $w = w(x,y)$ and I want to find $N(a,b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are variables independent of $x$.

\begin{equation}
N(a,b) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} w(ax,bx) dx
\end{equation}

Assuming the integral converges, is there a way to simplify this integral?

For example, in the 1D case I can use substitution to prove that:

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(ax) dx = \frac{1}{a}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx
\end{equation}

Is there a similar type of simplification I can do for the 2D case? Ideally, I'd like to suck the $a$ and $b$ outside the integral.

Comment: You could do $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(ax,bx)dx=\frac{1}{a}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,\frac{1}{a}x)dx=\frac{1}{b}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\frac{1}{b}x,x)dx$.

Comment: I beleive you mean $\frac{1}{a}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,\frac{b}{a}x)dx$. But is there a way to simplify this further in some sense? I realize that the term 'simplify' is a bit ambiguous in this case.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, that's what I meant.

Comment: @MatthewJames $f$ is too general here. I mean I could just define $g(x):= f(ax, bx)$ and obtain $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ax, bx) dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) dx$. But this is probably not what you want.

Comment: @FelixB. Thanks! I agree. What if I assume I know that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y) dx dy = k$. Is there a way to rewrite the original integral in terms of $k$ somehow?

Comment: Hmm, or perhaps it's possible to express the integral above in terms of $F$, where $\int \int f(x,y) dx dy = F(x,y)$?

Comment: $\int f(ax,bx)dx$ is integrating the function $f$ over the line $l_1=\{y=\frac{b}{a}x\}$. $\int f(x,x)dx$ is integrating the function $f$ over the line $l_2=\{y=x\}$. Substitution only changes how you parameterize the area you integrate over, it never changes the actual area. If you want to relate these two integrals, you will need to use specific information about $f$. For example if $f$ were radially symmetric, than the integrals will be the same up to some constant depending on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @AntonV. Thanks! I agree that if $f$ was radially symmetric then I can exploit that property. Sadly, in my problem $f$ can really be anything (it's the inverse Fourier transform of some generic function), so I can't exploit it. In reality, I also technically know what $f$ is numerically (as a 2D matrix of points), but I don't know the constants $a$ and $b$. It would be so great if I could somehow suck the constants $a$ and $b$ out of the integral somehow. In other words, I'm trying to find $N(a,b)$ where $N(a,b) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(ax,bx)dx$

Comment: A highly inefficient numerical solution I have at the moment is to plug in 100 values for $a$ and 100 values for $b$ and evaluate the integral numerically 10000 times to populate a matrix of values for $N(a,b)$

Comment: As @MathEnjoyer pointed out, you can use substitution to only have the ratio $b/a$ in the integral. This means you can be much more effecient in getting 10000 values for $N(a,b)$, by using 100 values for $b/a$ and 100 values for $a$. Only calculate the integral for each $b/a$ once and then $a$ is just a scaling factor.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you know $f$? You say you know $f$ as a matrix of points, is that matrix fixed or could you make it larger (knowing $f$ in more detail) if you wanted to?

Comment: @AntonV. That's a fantastic point! I didn't think about that. 

Sure, just as an aside I've renamed $f$ to be $w$ to separate my 1D example from my 2D problem. 

$w(x,y)$ is known and fixed. It is a n x n matrix of points ranging from $-1<x<1$ and $-1<y<1$. I also know that all values of $w$ outside the unit circle $x^2+y^2>1$ are approximately 0. This is why I'm confident that the integral (which goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$) will converge.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x,y)$ be the joint distribution of the random variables $X$ and $Y$, then
$$
\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
e(\epsilon) := \E[1_{B_\epsilon(X)}(Y)] = \int 1_{B_\epsilon(x)}(y) f(x,y) dx dy
= \int \int_{x-\epsilon}^{x+\epsilon} f(x,y) dy dx
$$
So under some  mild regularity conditions you can probably [exchange differentiation and integration](https://planetmath.org/differentiationundertheintegralsign) to get
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{\E[1_{B_\epsilon(X)}(Y)]}{2\epsilon} 
= e'(0) 
= \int \frac{d}{d\epsilon}\int_{x-\epsilon}^{x+\epsilon}f(x,y)dy\Bigr|_{\epsilon=0} dx
= \int f(x,x) dx
$$
Conditioning on zero probability sets is iffy, but you might be able to view this as
$$\begin{aligned}
\Pr(X\in A \mid X=Y) \Bigr("&=" \frac{\Pr(X\in A, Y=X)}{\Pr(X=Y)}\Bigr)\\
&\overset?= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} 
\frac{\Pr(X\in A, Y \in B_\epsilon(X))}
{\Pr(Y\in B_\epsilon(X))}\\
&= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{\E[1_A(X) 1_{B_\epsilon(X)}(Y)]}
{2\epsilon}
\frac{2\epsilon}{\E[1_{B_\epsilon(X)}(Y)]}\\
&= \frac{\int_A f(x,x) dx}{\int f(x,x)dx}
\end{aligned}
$$
I have not yet addressed your problem:
$$
\Pr(X\in A \mid aX= bY)
= \Pr(X\in A \mid X= \tfrac{b}{a}Y) 
\overset{\text{similarly}}=
\frac{\int_A f(x, \tfrac{b}a x)dx}{\int f(x, \tfrac{b}a x ) dx}
$$
Where you can justify the "similarly" with the distribution of $(X,\tilde{Y})$, where $\tilde{Y}=\frac{b}{a} Y$ or repeat the argument before.

I am not sure if this helps at all. But maybe this different frame of reference is all you need. Especially since you apparently have [?]
$$
F(x,y) = \int_{-\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^y f(t, s) ds dt
$$
which looks like a cumulative distribution function. [I mean you did not write these integral borders and used $x,y$ as integrands but that does not make sense, so I guessed.]

If you only have
$$
\int \int f(x,y) dx dy = k
$$
you have nothing, since you need to normalize $k$ to be $1$ for $f$ to even be a distribution. This still leaves you with plenty of options for "$\Pr(aX=bY)$" $= \int f(ax,bx)dx$.